# Cannot get all attributes when parsing XML file with python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, attributes

This is the XML file 'test_xml2.xml'

```
<feed xml:lang='en'>
  <title>HackerRank</title>
  <subtitle lang='en'>Programming challenges</subtitle>
  <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='http://hackerrank.com/'/>
  <updated>2013-12-25T12:00:00</updated>
  <entry>
    <author gender='male'>Harsh</author>
    <question type='hard'>XML 1</question>
    <description type='text'>This is related to XML parsing</description>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

It actually has 8 attributes.

But with my code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

count = 0
xml = 'test_xml2.xml'
tree = etree.parse(xml)
root = tree.getroot()
for item in root:
    count += len(item.attrib)
    print item.keys()
print count
```

I get result '4'.

> Could someone please tell me what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform the loop `for item in root:` it only iterates over the immediate children of `root` and not its descendants.

One way to meet your requirement would be to use the xpath - `.//*` to get all elements in the xml (as a list) and then iterate over that to get the list of attributes.

Please note, the xpath - `.//*` - will not return the `root` itself, so `count` needs to be initialized with length of root's attrib.

Example -

```
>>> count = len(root.attrib)
>>> elements = root.findall(".//*")
>>> for item in elements:
...     count += len(item.attrib)
...     print(item.keys())
[]
['lang']
['href', 'type', 'rel']
[]
[]
['gender']
['type']
['type']
>>> print(count)
8
```

Answer (score 1):

This loop:

```
for item in root:
    count += len(item.attrib)
```

iterates over the immediate children of `root`, not the grandchildren or deeper descendents.

Perhaps this will help:

```
for item in root.iter():
    count += len(item.attrib)
```

Answer (score 0):

The items in `root` are the `title`, `subtitle`, `link`, `updated` and `entry` nodes; `subtitle` has 1 attribute (`lang`) and `link` has 3 (`rel`, `type` and `href`): 4 attributes.

Your code needs to dive into the items in the items of `root` (`entry`, specifically).